# How can i pass transaction to each query automatically using sequelize (MySQL) and node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

A function that attached transaction to each query in sequelize(MySQL) means by not passing transaction to each query. Can someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CLS:

```js
const cls = require('cls-hooked');
const Sequelize = require('@sequelize/core');

const namespace = cls.createNamespace('my-very-own-namespace');
Sequelize.useCLS(namespace);

new Sequelize(....);
...
sequelize.transaction((t1) => {
  // With CLS enabled, the user will be created inside the transaction
  return User.create({ name: 'Alice' });
});
```

See [pass a transaction to all queries](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html#automatically-pass-transactions-to-all-queries)

Comment: Thanks for your time .. I am aware of that but can you please look into that.. `https://www.npmjs.com/package/zb-sequelize` i want like that

Comment: You can create a wrapper function to call `sequelize.transaction` and pass a callback there from a wrapper